# Modifying a GLM loop to drop a predictor and replace it with the next?

Tags: r, loops, glm

Currently this is my code:

```
mod_summaries<-list()

for(i in 20:ncol(data)){
  predictors<-colnames(data)[20:i]
  mod_summaries[[i-1]]<-summary(
    glm(y ~ .,  family=binomial, data=data[,c("y", "x1", "x2," "x3", predictors)])
  )
}

mod_summaries
```

My goal is to run many separate GLMs in which each separate model tests y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + [a predictor]. So x1, x2, and x3 will always be in the model, but it will run that model with predictor1, then the next model will drop predictor1 but add predictor 2, then the next will drop predictor2 and add predictor3, and so on and so forth for each predictor.

You can see the code above that I tried, and the result is that it is running all of the glms, but is adding each predictor successively without dropping the previous.

Comment: In your loop you’re only adding more predictors as the loop steps. Try ‘predictors <- colnames(data)[i]’

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.